# How do you mark English words originally used by a non-native author in an English translation?

Tags: translation, quotation-marks, style-manuals, italics, square-brackets

An artist has written memoirs in his native language with some English words and phrases scattered here and there (some might even have spelling / grammar mistakes). His memoirs are translated into English now. Are there any rules, how to mark those words and phrases, that are not part of the translation, but authors original speech? Quotation marks? Bold or italics? [Square brackets] maybe?

Comment: Not sure if this is the best place to ask as it's more about typography and translation than English, maybe someone can think of a better place. There's not a general rule, although italics could be used - in contrast, quotation marks or bold would look odd. You could use a footnote on an individual word if it's important (though obviously you don't want too many of them). Possibly you could mention in a footnote on the first instance of this, or in a translator's introduction, that the author is in the habit of doing this, and mention how you handle this.

Comment: I have often see Italics followed by numeral superscript referring to a footnote indicating for example "In Italian in the text"."

Comment: Hello, Lis. A very outlying topic, as @Stuart says. I should think this question may have been addressed on a site dedicated to translation. And 'Writing.SE' has both 'translation' and 'punctuation' tags. // Unless you really feel a need to observe niceties, I'd highlight the words in question in a way that won't get confused with other uses (italics are a great device, but so overworked) and point out your particular usage in an explanatory note. The odds are that people reading the passage won't know of any more established convention anyway, and this will at least be clear (Rule #1)..

Comment: This is a matter that would best settled between the translator, the original author and the editor.